# Why statistical mechanics has wider applicability than kinetic theory?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Both the kinetic theory of gases and statistical mechanics are microscopic theories of matter. Why is statistical mechanics has wider applicability?

Comment: From an historical perspective, kinetic theory is a precursor of statistical mechanics. From a modern perspective, it is a subset of statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

A thought-provoking question. My immediate thoughts are below.

(1) It's too hard to apply the methods of kinetic theory (based on the motion of molecules) to systems other than gases. The methods of statistical mechanics (considering the distribution of systems in different states according to the systems' energy levels and their degeneracies) is easier to apply to a greater variety of systems. (2) Statistical mechanics gives insights of a general nature (such as the microscopic interpretation of entropy) that are harder to achieve using kinetic theory.